# Задача Golang,подскажите с решением

Tags: golang

Найдите первое число от 1 до n включительно, кратное c, но НЕ кратное d.

Входные данные

Вводится 3 натуральных числа n, c, d, каждое из которых не превышает 10000.

Выходные данные
Вывести первое число от 1 до n включительно, кратное c, но НЕ кратное d. Если такого числа нет - выводить ничего не нужно.

Sample Input:

```
20
3
5
```

Sample Output:

```
3
```

```
package main

import "fmt"
func main() {
    var n int  
    var c int  
    var d int
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    fmt.Scan(&c)
    fmt.Scan(&d)
    for i := 1; i <= n; i++{
        if i % c == 0 && i % d != 0 {
            break
        }
    fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

не получается правильно вывести и скобки

Comment: Я бы предложил вынести логику поиска в отдельную функцию и return из неё при первом совпадении. `main` только читает числа и вызывает эту функцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы все сделали почти правильно.

`i % c == 0` - проверяем на кратность 
`i % d != 0` - проверяет что НЕ кратно.

нас должны удовлетворять оба условия. вы поставили оператор `И` и это тоже верно. 
проблема в том, что как только вы нашли это число(попали в if), вы выходите из цикла и не печатаете его.  надо немного поменять условие. как только нашли - печатаем его и потом уже выходим из цикла.

```
for i := 1; i <= n; i++{
    if i % c == 0 && i % d != 0 { 
        fmt.Println(i)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное,стало понятно почему не работало